# Optimal passing of optional parameters into a query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a parameterized query with optional parameters.
Multiple tables are joined. 
A part of the WHERE clause looks like this:

```
and ((x.a = @arg1) OR (@arg1 IS NULL))
and ((y.b = @arg2) OR (@arg2 IS NULL))
and ((z.c = @arg3) OR (@arg3 IS NULL))
```

So, the idea is: A parameter can either be used for applying a filter, or, if the parameter is NULL, then no filtering will be applied.

However, I found that the execution plan is not good for this code. 
When a parameter is actually set, then it is much better to write

```
and x.a = @arg1
```

instead of

```
and ((x.a= @arg1) OR (@arg1 IS NULL))
```

Actually, I have in total 8 tables which are joined together. In both statements, all 8 tables are joined, and there are the same index seeks/scans applied on all these tables. However, the join order is different, thus resulting in different execution speeds.

Is there a way to rewrite the above statement, such that the execution plan can work optimal? Possibly with some query hints ?

Or is there no way around writing dynamic SQL? I want to avoid the latter, because

- dynamic SQL is hard to read,
- SSMS does not show dependencies,
- passing the parameters into the dynamic SQL is awful

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the best solution for this task from a performance perspective. Although you are correct about the dependencies, it shouldn't be hard to read if good coding practices are followed.  Not sure I understand about the difficulty in passing parameters.

Comment: Parameter passing into a DynSQL is not really difficult, I just dislike the way you need to "tunnel" each parameter into the DynSQL, by creating an "inside" parameter for each "outside" parameter, and then passing the whole thing into the exec function. but well. ;)

Comment: You can declare all of the `inside` parameters in the declaration string passed to sp_executesql and map the `inside/outside` parameter values unconditionally.  The key to performance is building the WHERE clause conditionally such that only the predicates actually needed for the search are specified.

Answer (score 0):

try using `COALESCE(@arg1, x.a)` instead of `((x.a = @arg1) OR (@arg1 IS NULL))`

```
and x.a = COALESCE(@arg1, x.a)
and y.b = COALESCE(@arg2, xyb)
and z.c = COALESCE(@arg3, z.c)
```

Comment: Good idea, but it results in the same :(

Comment: Then I guess `x.a = CASE WHEN @arg1 IS NULL THEN x.a ELSE @arg1 END` will not help either, but it's worth a try. can you post the execution plan? whatever you do, dynamic sql should be considered only as a last resort.

Comment: Yes, `CASE WHEN` results in the same. The actual statement joins 8 tables, so the execution plan is rather big. Will try to post it somehow.

Comment: In both cases, all 8 tables are joined, and there are the exact same index seeks/scans applied on all these tables. However, the join order is different, thus resulting in different execution speeds.

Comment: Just FYI: `COALESCE`or `CASE` are better than my original query, but still worse than the hand-written variant without case handling. Original Query = 620ms; COALESCE/CASE = 290 ms; hand-written = 90 ms (multiple tries in all cases)

Comment: It's very hard to optimize a query you know nothing about. [perhaps this link will help.](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)

Comment: Great link, it describes exactly my problem. See the other answer here -- `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` in combination with your `COALESCE` now comes close to the optimal case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the optimiser will tend to stick with whatever plan suits the first invocation.  Your best options are to write a stored procedure for each combination (or at least the major ones) or try `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` which will take the time to evaluate the actual parameters, but at some cost.

To answer your question about "Is there a way to rewrite the above statement, such that the execution plan can work optimal?", the answer is probably not.  There are too many variations to come up with a single plan with so many things that may not occur (your null variables).

Comment: Yes, `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` is good! In combinaton with the `COALESCE` variant [@ZoharPeled], it results in the same execution plan like the hand-written variant. Only the recompile time costs around 70ms extra time, that's a drawback. So I will stick to a combination of all answers here.